# SwiftUI change list item when pressed

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

Supposing I have a simple view with a list:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var names = ["Bob","John","Lisa"]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach (names, id: \.self) {name in
                Detail(name: name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would I achieve for the list item to change on press? The `Detail` would presumably look something like:

```
struct Detail: View {
    
    var name: String
    
    var body: some View {
        if !inFocus {
            Text(name)
        } else {
            Text("This is a detail view")
            Text(name)
            Text("---------------------")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Store whether an item has been pressed in a `@State` variable and render the difference based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ou can try a few things like this with @State variable

```
struct Detail: View {
var name: String
@State var inFocus = false
var body: some View {
    if !inFocus {
        Text(name)
            .onTapGesture{
                self.inFocus.toggle()
            }
    } else {
        VStack{
            Text("This is a detail view")
            Text(name)
            Text("---------------------")
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            self.inFocus.toggle()
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Right... .onTapGesture is what I was missing; thanks a lot!